# Finding intersection on Heterogenous sets

Tags: set-theory

I am having a rather simple problem that looks on paper that would involve set theory. I am aware of the basic set theory principles like Union, Intersection, Commutativness, etc., However, I would like to find the intersection of a heterogenous set (don't know if this is even a term). To get to the problem, here is what I am trying to solve.

There are four dimensions in my problem set where I need to find whether one Set with a maximum possibility of 4 dimensions would intersect with another Set with a similar dimension. To explain it with an example

I have a region dimension whose complete set includes all the states of the United States. So the entire set R will comprise

`R = [Alabama, Alaska, Arizona ...., Wyoming]`

I also have another dimension say car brands in USA. And let C be all the car brands. So,

`C = [Audi, BMW, Ford, Toyota..., Chrysler]`

Now I need to find the intersection of these two different dimensions. If it were just the intersection within the same dimension, its straight forward. Again, let me say the examples.

```
S1 ========= R1 = [California, Arizona] and C1 = [BMW, Chrysler]

vs

S2 ========= R2 = [Wyoming] and C2=[BMW, Tesla]
```

In the above example S1 ∩ S2 is going to be empty because the regions are entirely different, so no further need to dive into the Car brands further.

However, in the below example

```
S1 ========= R1 = R (the entire region set) and C1=[Tesla]

vs

S2 ========= R2 = [California] and C2=[Tesla, Audi]
```

Here, S1 ∩ S2 = [California] [Tesla]

**Questions**

1. How do I model this in a program?
2. Also what is the result of something like `S1 U S2`? How do I represent it?
3. Any pointers/pseudo code, mathematical formulas to attack this problem would be greatly helpful.

Please note that the number of dimensions used in the above example is 2. In the problem that I am trying to solve, the dimensions are 4 and would increase in future. What is the best way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description is a little unclear, but I think you're talking about the intersection of **Cartesian products**.

Specifically, you have two "starting sets" $R$ and $C$, and the sets whose intersections you're interested in taking are subsets of $R\times C$, that is, sets whose elements are *pairs* with first coordinate from $R$ and second coordinate from $C$.

In fact, even more specifically you're looking at "subproducts" of $R\times C$ - subsets of $R\times C$ which have the form $R'\times C'$ for some $R'\subseteq R$ and $C'\subseteq C$. (Not every subset of $R\times C$ will be of this form: consider e.g. something of the form $\{(a,c), (a,d), (b,c)\}$.) Intersections of Cartesian products turn out to be pretty easy to calculate: we always have $$(A\times B)\cap (A'\times B')=(A\cap A')\times (B\cap B').$$

*(Note that unions are a bit more annoying: $(A\times B)\cup(A'\times B')$ is **not** the same thing as $(A\cup A')\times(B\cup B')$.)*

Comment: thank you for your answer!